# Eclipse downloads non requested files

Tags: eclipse, auto-update

I am working with my Eclipse Mars and since yesterday, without me asking for it, it started downloading some files like updates/4.5/compositeContent.xml.

Sometimes it tells it is synchronizing with Tern server.

What is it about? How can I disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable or change auto-updates in the Preferences, under **Install/Update** > **Automatic Updates**.

[image]

Comment: The fact is the part "and notify me" was ignored

Comment: No, the notification is that there are, in fact, updates available. It has to contact the update sites to know if there is anything to update. That's what the downloading of 'compositeContent.xml' is about - discovering if there are any updates available.